# How do I prevent a platform specific ValueError in python when calling C++ code?

Tags: python, c++, linux, cross-platform

I am working on a python script that calls C++ code. It is working fine when the C++ code is compiled in a cygwin (in Clion) environment and when I run the script in Windows. However, I used Clion to create a .so file in Linux (Ubuntu, WSL) too, using the same code and cmake file.My C++ code compiles for both patforms. My python code runs on both platforms (python 3.5). However, I get an error in Linux.

Here is my C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>

wchar_t * DoSomeThingUseful(wchar_t * input)
{
    wchar_t* output = new wchar_t[2];
    output[0] = input[0];
    output[1] = 'x';
    return output;
}

extern "C" {
    wchar_t * GetJsonFromJson(wchar_t * input)
    {
        wchar_t * output = DoSomeThingUseful(input);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Here is my cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(ExternalFacade)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(ExternalFacade SHARED library.cpp)
```

Here is the python code.

```
from ctypes import *
import os.path
import platform
print('Hello')
operating_system = platform.system()
if operating_system == 'Windows':
    library_path = 'C:/Users/Daant/CLionProjects/Share/cmake-build-release/cygExternalFacade.dll'
else:
    library_path = '/mnt/c/Users/Daant/CLionProjects/Share/cmake-build-release/libExternalFacade.so'

itExist = os.path.exists(library_path)
print(itExist)
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(library_path)
print('dll loaded')
lib.GetJsonFromJson.restype = c_wchar_p
input = c_wchar_p('aaa')
memoRefToOutput = lib.GetJsonFromJson(input)
print(memoRefToOutput)
print('End')
```

Here is the output when running it on Windows.

```
Hello
True
dll loaded
ax
End
```

Here is the output when running it on Linux.

```
Hello
True
dll loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CallFacade.py", line 17, in <module>
    memoRefToOutput = lib.GetJsonFromJson(input)
ValueError: character U+214bae0 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

I do not understand why my code could possibly work fine on Windows but not on Linux. Ctypes are Ctypes.... Can anyone explain how I should fix it?

Comment: Probably has to do with `wchar_t` and C++’s Unicode support having room for improvement.  Can you do everything in UTF-8?

Comment: For both files, (C++ and python) I already use UTF-8.

Comment: Then don't use `wchar_t` for UTF-8.  That's probably where things are going poorly.

Comment: in C `wchart_t` is compiler dependent so that probably has to do with the reason you're getting an error. My guess is that clion is more strict on checking whether something is within range Unicode. `21bae0` is beyond the range of Unicode characters as the error suggests.